# KerberosAuthenticationProvider vs. KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, kerberos, spring-security-kerberos

Moin!

I use Spring Security 5 with Kerberos for the SSO authentication in my project.

In the `WebSecurityConfig` I register two `AuthenticationProvider`

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(msfUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        assertThatUnlimitedCryptographyEnabled();

        // Two providers
        auth.authenticationProvider(kerberosAuthenticationProvider());
        auth.authenticationProvider(kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider());
}
```

This seems to be the way its done as seen in these two examples:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-kerberos/docs/current/reference/html/ssk-spnego.html
- https://www.ebayinc.com/stories/blogs/tech/customizing-spring-security-with-multiple-authentications/

However I don't see why I need both of them. During authentication the `KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider` is the one that is validating Kerberos tickets (see [JavaDoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/extensions/krb/docs/1.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/extensions/kerberos/KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider.html))

However what is the `KerberosAuthenticationProvider` for? The [JavaDoc](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-kerberos/1.0.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/kerberos/authentication/KerberosAuthenticationProvider.html) in this case just says

> AuthenticationProvider for kerberos.

Comment: Did you try it without `KerberosAuthenticationProvider`? What happend? It is only needed for form login or HTTP basic login. I think, it is only needed as a fallback, no SSO is possible.

Comment: You are right, it works without. The chain of AuthenticationProvider contains a DaoAuthenticationProvider at the end which handles password credentials. So far the KerberosAuthenticationProvider seems to be not needed at all. Maybe the DaoAuthenticationProvider is missing in older versions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said: `KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider` is used to validate tickets in SSO authentication, whereas `KerberosAuthenticationProvider` is used for form based authentications, which are usually used as a fallback when SSO is not supported on client side (e.g. browsers on linux systems). This type of authentication is handled by `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` which is applied in `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
     httpSecurity
      ...
      .formLogin()
  ...
  }
  ...
}
```

If you do not use form login then you can omit this provider as pointed in comments.